# Obj C ui segmented control to de/activate a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol

everyone,

I can't get a segmentedcontrol in an older Objective c app to activate or deactivate another button.

I have tried the following so far:
I have linked the button and SegmentedControl to the same IBAction.
SegmentedControl -> Sent Event: -> Value Changed -> File's Owner: *clearHighScore:*
Button -> Sent Event: -> Touch Up Inside -> File's Owner *clearHighScore:*

HighScoreViewController.m :

```
#import "HighScoreViewController.h"
@synthesize segmentedControl;    

- (IBAction)clearHighScore:(id)sender {

        if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {}
        else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
                deletes.A.table;
        }
    }
```

HighScoreViewController.m :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (IBAction)clearHighScore:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
```

I also tried to link the SegmentedControl to a different IBAction in HighScoreViewController.m : (I know that it would be reduntand)

```
- (IBAction)activateClearHighScoreButton:(id)sender {
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;
            break;
        default:self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
            break;
    }
}

- (IBAction)clearHighScore:(id)sender {

    if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {}
    else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
            deletes.A.table;
    }
}
```

I think I am missing the value transfer into *(IBAction)clearHighScore*
but I don't know how to solve this problem.

(The reason to do this is to have a invisible button which deletes data but is only clickable/active if the invisible switch was clicked.
Alternatively, I would like to have a password prompted by clicking on the button, after which the data will be deleted.
However, I have even less idea how to implement this.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is confusing. You have a SegmentedControl... and you have an invisible button... when the user changes the selected segment, you want to change the button's visibility? Or you want to keep the button invisible, but allow an action if it's tapped?

Comment: I want to keep both invisible (alpha 0). I want to allow an action if the segmented control ist tapped.

Comment: You want to *"allow an action if the segmented control ist tapped"*? Do you mean you want to execute a Method when its tapped? Or do you want to ***enable*** another control?

Comment: I want to enable another control (the button which is linked with clearHighScore method). The segmented control has to activate/deactivate this "clearHighScore" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set it up as follows.

- Connect your button to outlet `clearButton`.
- Connect your segmentedControl to outlet `segmentedControl`
- Connect the buttons `Touch Up Inside` to `clearHighScore`
- Connect the segmentedControl's `valueChanged` to `activateClearHighScoreButton`

The button will now be enabled/disabled when you tap on the segmented control.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *clearButton;

- (IBAction)clearHighScore:(id)sender {
    if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {}
    else if (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
            deletes.A.table;
    }
}

- (IBAction)activateClearHighScoreButton:(id)sender {
    switch (self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            _clearButton.enabled = NO;
            break;
        case 1:
            _clearButton.enabled = YES;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. :) I just had to at an underscore before the "clearButton.enabled...." like "_clearButton.enabled..."